# Why do these complex patterns emerge from a simple iteration?

Tags: graphing-functions, recreational-mathematics

I was playing around with some simple turtle code a few months ago and found a very neat and complex pattern emerging from a [simple code](https://turtletoy.net/turtle/91b7bd4cff). I also noticed that changing the $x$ to $x2^n$ where $n$ is any whole number also made some neat patterns, as well as to $x^3n$, yet not to $x^2n$. Is there any reason for these emerging patterns?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site.

Comment: It would help if you explain your iteration in the post, people may not be familiar with Python. Does it move forward, then turn by a multiple of 360°, and move forward again?